# Include Maven Site HTML pages in JAR's resources

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I've got a Maven project that builds a JAR file.

It also creates a site (using `maven-site-plugin`) that describes information about the project.

I'd like to include the resultant html pages generated by the `maven-site-plugin` in the resources of the created JAR so that they can be accessed at runtime by a help system.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I've tried using the `site:jar` goal but this always creates an *additional* JAR with "-site" appended, as per the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/jar-mojo.html#finalName).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by using `maven-resources-plugin` to copy the `site` from the `${project.build.directory}/site` directory to `${project.build.directory}/classes`, which is the contents of the final JAR.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.me</groupId>
   <artifactId>site-example</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <properties>
      <site.directory>${project.build.directory}/site</site.directory>
   </properties>
   <build>
      <resources>
         <resource>
            <directory>${site.directory}</directory>
         </resource>
      </resources>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <!-- Include the maven site in the final JAR - we do this by running site:site BEFORE install -->
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>copy-resources</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                     <resources>
                        <resource>
                           <directory>${site.directory}</directory>
                           <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                     </resources>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Comment: can you show the configuration made?

Comment: @BrunoLee I've added an example :)